# Collection report for defined pattern in Unix using grep & awk?

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file like this:

```
abc:: vvnm\/asj\/pqr
 sadnck
 acdsd
abc:: kfjwej\/asj\/pqr
 frtrt
 ewrfe
 adsf
abc:: flkm\/csj\/lqr
abc:: kmflkm\/asj\/pqr
 sdvd
 dfff
```

I want to output like this [after :abc, count cell]

```
3 kfjwej/asj/pqr
2 vvnm/asj/pqr
2 kmflkm/asj/pqr
0 flkm/csj/lqr
```

Comment: not getting result if have zero cell for abc, some more help, how to make first column number list from highest to lowest order

Answer (score 1):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^[0-9]+:abc /{
         if (abc) print count abc;
         sub(/^[0-9]+/, "");
         abc = $0; count = 0; next
     }
     abc{ count++ }
     END{ print count abc }' file
```

The output:

```
2:abc vvvvv
3:abc kfjwej
2:abc kmflkm
```

---

Additional (and last) approach for your new file format using `awk` *source-file*:

**`count_abc.awk`** script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
/^abc::/{ 
    if (abc) print count, abc;
    gsub(/\\/, "", $2);
    abc = $2; count = 0; next 
}
abc { count++ }
END { print count, abc }
```

---

Usage:

```
awk -f count_abc.awk newfile
```

The output:

```
2 vvnm/asj/pqr
3 kfjwej/asj/pqr
2 kmflkm/asj/pqr
```

Comment: please help for modified question, i want one line script, which i can source on terminal

Comment: @SaurabhShukla, see my update

Comment: not getting result if have zero cell for abc, some more help, how to make first column number list from highest to lowest order . please see latest modified question

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of `sed`, `uniq`, and `awk`:

```
$ sed '/^[^[:space:]]/{s/^[^[:space:]]* //g;s#\\##g;h;}; g' file | uniq -c | awk '{ $1 -= 1; print }'
2 vvnm/asj/pqr
3 kfjwej/asj/pqr
0 flkm/csj/lqr
2 kmflkm/asj/pqr
```

The `sed` script, annotated:

```
/^[^[:space:]]/{             # this line starts with a non-space
    s/^[^[:space:]]* //;     # remove the thing that is not a space, up to the space
    s#\\##g;                 # remove backslashes
    h;                       # store in hold space
};

g;                           # get hold space
                             # (implicit print)
```

What this does is replacing each "sub-header line" with its corresponding "header line", generating

```
vvnm/asj/pqr
vvnm/asj/pqr
vvnm/asj/pqr
kfjwej/asj/pqr
kfjwej/asj/pqr
kfjwej/asj/pqr
kfjwej/asj/pqr
flkm/csj/lqr
kmflkm/asj/pqr
kmflkm/asj/pqr
kmflkm/asj/pqr
```

We then let `uniq` count the number of consecutive unique lines, generating

```
   3 vvnm/asj/pqr
   4 kfjwej/asj/pqr
   1 flkm/csj/lqr
   3 kmflkm/asj/pqr
```

With `awk`, we then simply decrement the number in the first field of this.

Comment: not getting result if have zero cell for abc,

Comment: @SaurabhShukla I don't know what you mean.